# Is it possible to pause scrollbar on clicking on button in WPF without using threading

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, pause

pause scrollbar by clicking on button.

```
public button_click(object sender)
    {
    //How can I stop scrollbar of any window
    }
```

I have tried:

```
Thread.Sleep()
```

but it is only for particular seconds we want to pause for scrollbar till user want.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Please can you add the code that you've tried?